# Rest Framework Serializer Method Field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

```
class BagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bag
        fields = ('order_date')

    def get_order_date(self, obj):
        print('Order date called', obj)
```

This is the view:

```
class BagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Bag.objects.all()
serializer_class = BagSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        try:
            print('Inside create viewset')
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                print('serializer passed', serializer.validated_data)
            else:
                print('Serializer failed', serializer.errors)
                return Response(serializer.errors)
        except Exception as e:
        print('exception raised--------', e)
    return Response('Boom')
```

The serializer method field is not being called and its data is too not shown in the validated_data and the serializer's is_valid() method returns True.
Why aint it considering the serializer method fields

Comment: Serializer method field are read only - therefore they won't be in validated data.

Comment: Note that the value of `fields` should be a tuple, not a string as in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is read-only field. From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only):

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
>   included in the input during create or update operations. Any
>   'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
>   input will be ignored.

If `order_date` realeted with some model field, you can just use `DateField` with `source` argument:

```
order_date = serializers.DateField(source='model_field_name')
```

Comment: I have a json from which I want to extract the vale and insert it in the db. So the serializer method field will be extracting and returning that value from the json.
How can I do that?

Comment: @Arjunsingh does `order_date` related with some model's field?

Comment: @Arjunsingh so you can simply use `DateField`.

Comment: I have declared it as a date field in the model.
So you mean to say that inside create method of serializer, extract the date from the json in request.data and save the serializer?

Comment: @Arjunsingh yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170628/discussion-between-arjunsingh-and-neverwalkaloner).

Comment: But why is the serializer method field not being called?

Comment: @Arjunsingh because its calling only during serializing object to json. Not during creating object fron json.